# How to check quality of code on Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have a big problem with quality of code when developers commit code to Github or Bitbucket. Sometimes, developers they can check and remove warning from their code. It's not good for product. 
Currently, I'm using Jenkins server for auto build and check warning. However, Jenkins server just show number of warning only.

[image]

Now, I want to check who created a warnings on Jenkins server and then server will be sent message to their.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to solve this (in my opinion) is to make developers use pull requests for their changes.

You can configure Jenkins and Github/Bitbucket to automatically build/check all pull requests, and allow merges to your master branch only if that check succeeds.